# Datasource can't be bound because it isn't a known property of table - angular4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a table using angular material in angular 4 and keep getting this error:

Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dataSource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'.

I have imported MatTableModule in @NgModule in my app.module.ts file. The way I'm using the table tags are like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Comment: Do you have any other module ?

Comment: What component is that `<table mat-table...>` line found in? Is that component found in your `app.module.ts` module or used in another? If it is in another, then you will need to import the `MatTableModule` in that module.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

to

```
<mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Comment: This should not be the answer. The documentation shows it both ways. https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical problem of modules importing, check if your component is in the same module where the MatTableModule are being imported. If it's all right, try running the app again.